# Understanding Spritekit run block, variable not as expected

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm looking for some help understanding why my `speedToPoint` variable is always `1` when it gets to the `wait` action.

This is part of an SKSpriteNode extension i wrote for making a bird fly to a random point in a predefined rectangle.  The `speedToPoint` is also randomized between 1 and 4 and used as the duration for the `moveTo` action.  However, i also need to use that `TimeInterval` for my wait block in the action sequence.

`speedToPoint` is indeed being randomized in the run block (i've confirmed).  How can i use that same randomized number in the wait block in the next part of the sequence?

```
var speedToPoint:TimeInterval = 1

self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(
     SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run{
            speedToPoint = TimeInterval(Globals.sharedInstance.randomF(min: 1, max: 4))
            var pointX = Globals.sharedInstance.randomF(min: left,max: right)
            let pointY = Globals.sharedInstance.randomF(min: top,max:bottom)

        while abs(self.position.x.distance(to: pointX)) < 200 {
            pointX = Globals.sharedInstance.randomF(min: left,max: right)
        }

        self.xScale = pointX < self.position.x ? -1 : 1

        self.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:pointX,y:pointY),duration: speedToPoint))
    },
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: speedToPoint)])
),withKey: "inFrame")
```

To clarify, what i'm really tring to do is have the bird fly to a point, once it's arrived at that point, fly to another point.  I'm still wrapping my heard around action sequences and whether or not they actually wait for completion to move on.  Which from what i've read, they do, but not for any `move` actions.  That's why the `wait` is in there.  Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: I've discovered it has to do with the run block closure, since that runs asynchronously the variable is not changed in time.  I found a work around that works for me, but I'm really curious on the correct way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `SKAction`, once created, can't be modified, and it is meant to be reused eg. you can't modify the duration parameter, or change other passed parameters. This means that you have to re-create it if you need it changed. Of course you can change the speed property of an existing action, or you can pause the action but that's pretty much it when it comes to modifying the existing action.

To solve your issue, you could do next:

1) Create an action which moves a sprite to a specific location

2) Once the action is completed, you create a new one which does the same

you can do this using recursion, like this (just copy & paste the code to see how it works):

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


    private var bird = SKSpriteNode(color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        addChild(bird)
        recursive()

    }

    func recursive(){

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([

           SKAction.move(to: self.randomPoint(inRect: self.frame), duration: TimeInterval(self.random(between: 1, and: 3))),

            SKAction.run({[unowned self] in NSLog("Block executed"); self.recursive()})
            ])

        self.bird.run(sequence, withKey: "aKey")
    }

    func random(between minimum: CGFloat, and maximum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(minimum - maximum) + min(minimum, maximum)
}

    func randomPoint(inRect rect:CGRect)->CGPoint{


        let x = random( between: -rect.size.width / 2.0 , and: rect.origin.x + rect.size.width/2.0)
        let y = random(between: -rect.size.height / 2.0 , and: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2.0)

        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)


    }

}
```

To stop this action, remove the key associated with it.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, I did not know that's called a recursive function.  What does the `[unowned self]` do in the run block closure?  Is there no way to make it work doing it my original way?  I never tried to change an action, only a variable used in the action.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Recursive method is a method which calls itself... [unowned self] protects you from creating a strong reference cycle. About your other questions...Actually you have tried to change an action - you are passing speedToPoint variable (as a duration parameter of a wait action) and expecting to have a different value each time. That is impossible in the way you do it because an action, once created, can't be modified, like I stated in my answer. Hope this make sense and is helpful.

Comment: Hay does make sense.  Thank you.  Don't quite understand the strong reference cycle part but I'll do some reading.